# Where is my Cordova app stored on Android 5?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to view my app files using file browser such as ES File Explorer.
Where is it stored?

I'm using Android 5.1 on Nexus 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All apps and their data are stored inside

```
/data/data/your.package.name/
```

Although you might not be able to see that directory. You can see them though through adb with

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/your.package.name/
ls
```

Comment: Also you will need root access to view those files. But even there you won't find html or css files.